# Let $f(x)=2x-x^{2}$, find the range $r(f(x))$ of the function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I need to check whether my solutions are correct for the following problems:

- $1)$ Let $f(x)=2x-x^{2}$, find $r(f(x))$.

**My solution**: $r(f(x))=(-\infty,1]$

- $2)$ Let $f(x)=x^{2}-7x+10$. Find $f\left((0,6]\right)$ and $f^{-1}((4,10])$.

**My solution**: $f((0,6])=[-2.25,10)$ and $ f^{-1}((4,10])=[0,7]$

I solved these 2 by looking at their graphs.

Comment: The $f(f(x))$ is wrong ($f(x)$ gives you number, not interval). Also the $f^{-1}((4,10])$ seems to be wrong (for example $f(3)=-2$ and $-2$ is not in $((4,10])$).

Comment: With $f(f(x))$ you denote the range of $f(x)$ or the function $f\circ f(x)$?

Comment: @JimmyR. range of $f(x)$

Comment: Ok, then do you mind if I change it to $\mathrm{Range}(f(x))$ to avoid confusion?

Comment: Not at all, go ahead.

Comment: @Sil How does $f(x)$ give me a number?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely In this case you take $x$ (a number) and assign it value of $2x-x^2$ (also a number).

Comment: @Sil is $f^{-1}((4,10])=[0,1)\cup(6,7]$?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely That looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Hint** 
   $$
   f(f(x))=2 f(x)-(f(x))^2
   $$

Comment: I think $f(f(x))$ denotes the range of $f(x)$.

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely That would be only if $f(x)$ would be set, and that would be in turn usually if $x$ would be a set. It is quite uncommon to denote set with small letters, I am pretty confident this is just composition of $f$. But what do I know...

Comment: @Leox, I know I'm a bit late to reply, but can you tell me is $f(f(x))=-x^{4}+4x^{3}-6x^{2}+4x$?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely, Yes